# VirtualBox error Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) on Debian 10

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I disable the secure boot on my laptop but this problem persist.

I used debian 10 and I installed virtualbox thanks to this website: https://tecadmin.net/install-virtualbox-on-debian-10-buster/

But when I launch Virtualbox, I have always this error message: **Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**

[image]

This is the output `/sbin/vboxconfig`:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

And the last line of `dmesg`:

```
[ 2771.515718] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000040fae4f7, val ffffffffc12034cf
```

I tried `modprobe -v vboxdrv` but I got the following error:

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.19.0-5-amd64/misc/vboxdrv.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Exec format error
```

Comment: What does the log file `/var/log/vbox-setup.log` say? If you do what the error message says and run `/sbin/vboxconfig` as root (e.g. `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` if you have `sudo` installed), what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18904

I update my kernel `linux-image-4.19.0-5-amd64` to `linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64-unsigned`.

According to the virtualbox ticket, the unsigned kernel maybe do a difference.

To upgrade the kernel:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64-unsigned
```

Comment: Installing `linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64` should have the same effect, the problem lies in the linux-image-4.19.0-5-amd64 / linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64 combo

Comment: @JavierLópez can you elaborate more. I have the same problem as the OP. If I do `hostnamectl` I get: `Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS, Kernel: Linux 3.19.0-80-generic and Architecture: x86_64`.